# Pandas pivot_table multiple aggfunc with margins

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

I've noticed that I can't set margins=True when having multiple aggfunc such as ("count","mean","sum").

It will vomit `KeyError: 'Level None not found'`

This is the example code.

```
df.pivot_table(values=A,index=[B,C,D],columns=E,aggfunc=("count","mean","sum"),
margins=True,margins_name="Total",fill_value=0)
```

**Update:**

This is the sample df:

```
[{'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'}]
```

And the code throwing errors.

```
df.pivot_table(values="Results",index="Game_ID",
columns="Team",aggfunc=("count","mean","sum"),margins=True)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your df so that we can test the code

Comment: Thx for your reply, I've update the question with sample frame.

Comment: I got the very same problem with every single df I have been working with in the past weeks

Answer (score 4):

I see the error you are talking about. I got around it by using the function calls instead of the string names "count","mean", and "sum."

First, we start with your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([{'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 1, 'Team': 'A'},
 {'Game_ID': 'no.1', 'Results': 0, 'Team': 'B'}])
```

Then just replace the aggregate functions with standard library call to `len` and the numpy aggregate functions.

- "count" becomes len
- "mean" becomes np.mean
- "sum" becomes np.sum

The pivot table is made with the following lines:

```
import numpy as np
df.pivot_table(values="Results",
               index="Game_ID",
               columns="Team",
               aggfunc=[len,np.mean,np.sum],
               margins=True)
```

[image: Output pivot table]

Note, `len` might not be what you want, but in this example it gives the same answer as "count" would on its own. Look at `numpy.count_nonzero`, for example.